# Minimize MSE for only some parameters

Tags: least-squares, bias-variance-tradeoff, gauss-markov-theorem

Suppose I have a structural model parameterized by some $\theta = (\beta_i)_{i=1}^n$, but I am only interested in obtaining an unbiased/consistent/low variance estimator for $\beta_1$. For example, let's say I have the model $y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x + \varepsilon$, where $E[\varepsilon|x] = 0$, but I am only interested in estimating $\beta_1$. OLS gives me a BLUE estimator for $\beta = (\beta_0, \beta_1)$, but can I "trade off" efficiency of $\hat{\beta}_0$ to get a lower variance for $\hat{\beta}_1$?

A related question is: Does the Gauss-Markov Theorem state that each parameter estimate by OLS $\hat{\beta}_i$ is BLUE, or that the aggregate vector $\hat{\theta}$ is BLUE?

Comment: Probably relevant: [Focused Information Criterion (FIC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Focused_information_criterion). Other than that, I suggest you split your questions into two posts. The questions are distinct enough for that.

Comment: This is an extremely interesting question. Consider how many times we run a regression with “control” variables but only care about a few parameters (not the ones one the controls). If we could improve the estimates of those parameters of interest by sacrificing the quality of the estimates of those covariates who estimates are not so important, that would be pretty cool! // I’m with @RichardHardy that this should be split into multiple questions (probably three, since the title seems to be yet a third question).

Comment: @Dave, at least for a classical linear regression, assuming such a tuning is possible and this tuned estimator is also linear and unbiased for the parameter of interest, we could tune for each parameter separately. We thus obtain an unbiased and lower variance estimator for the full vector of parameters, contradicting that OLS is BLUE. If we allow bias, then a whole literature on minimax MSE becomes relevant. Also, maybe there’s an opportunity if we break the symmetry in the problem setup?

Comment: I’ll split up the post. Just wanted to put that comment out.

Comment: It’s definitely true that OLS is BLUE under the Gauss-Markov conditions. While there is nothing wrong with these, I would expect your tuning to be nonlinear or biased, maybe both.

Comment: Yes exactly - I was arguing (by contradiction) that a linear and unbiased tuned estimator is impossible. I wasn’t claiming that the Gauss-Markov theorem is wrong.